# WCF Service not working for post service

Tags: c#, wcf

http://wishisdone.com/IphoneService.svc/echoWithPost
Key:S
Value: Welcome

Below the error:

[service help page](http://wishisdone.com/IphoneService.svc/help)

> for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message
>   is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The
>   expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can
>   be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the
>   binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more
>   details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace
>   is:

Comment: please use authorisation first as your methods are publicly accessible.

Comment: it is authorisation  for publicly accessible. please use postman for access this service:
http://wishisdone.com/IphoneService.svc/echoWithPost Key:S Value: Welcome

Comment: [have you verified this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123619/wcf-service-error-incoming-message-has-an-unexpected-message-format-raw-exp) with similar issue

Answer (score 0):

parameter shold be in json format
{"EmployeeId":"601"}.use firefox restclient to check error.

Comment: i used restclient for this but is is throwing error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'There was an error checking start element of object of type System.String. Encountered unexpected character 's'.'. See server logs for more details.

Comment: Can you please let me confirm what is the exact error.?

Comment: in  restclient you have to add header content-type:application-json.

Comment: run service on local host and add debugger to code to check error using restclient

Comment: your error is pasing error in your code according to me

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

HTTP POST : http://wishisdone.com/IphoneService.svc/echoWithPost?content=Hello

This returned me status 200 OK. XML returned is

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    Post: 
</string>
```

The reason is that string is a primitive data type and so, even though the HTTP Request a POST it should be appended as a querystring.

Comment: Sir it is showing  public string echoWithPost(string s)
        {
            return "Post: " + s;
        }
But not your message you type on query string.